# flutter D/libc-netbsd(20664): getaddrinfo: www.website.com get result from proxy

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am new to flutter and android. Created 2 apps, 1 is fully using REST Api and other not. The App that use REST data, I Tested on LG devices and emulator works fine but recently i tested on 'alcatel one touch' using Jelly Beans 4.2.2 and strange thing happened.

As you can see the logs

```
flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on ALCATEL ONETOUCH 7041D in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                      3.8s
Resolving dependencies...                      3.2s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                      3.2s
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 7041D...
D/libc-netbsd(21905): getaddrinfo: www.mysite.com get result from proxy >>
D/libc-netbsd(21905): getaddrinfo: www.mysite.com get result from proxy >>
3.9s

To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 7041D is available at: http://127.0.0.1:58995/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".
D/libc-netbsd(21905): getaddrinfo: www.mysite.com get result from proxy >>
D/libc-netbsd(21905): getaddrinfo: www.mysite.com get result from proxy >>
D/libc-netbsd(21905): getaddrinfo: www.mysite.com get result from proxy >>
D/libc-netbsd(21905): getaddrinfo: www.mysite.com get result from proxy >>
```

On the phone i see this message "Sorry AppName has stopped working"

However the other app without REST Api works fine.

I don't know whats happening.